# Is there a limit on the number of socket connection that can be opened in iOS?

Tags: ios, sockets, connection, limits, network-connection

Reading [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/CH73-SW1) and [this one](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/CommonPitfalls/CommonPitfalls.html) I couldn't find a reference on the maximum number of socket connection that can be opened in iOS.

Does anyone know it? Have I missed it from the documentation?

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Jetfire](https://github.com/acmacalister/jetfire) I **tried** to run **100** simultaneous socket connections to the server, but **only 64 were running** at the same time.

Obviously it is a limitation for your app, not iOS in general as you ask.